# How can I control substring length by ending it with a specific character?

Tags: c++, substring

I have a string, "s", which I would like to obtain a substring of by starting a the begging (position 0), and end at a space- so that if someone were to, for instance, enter their full name, I could determine their first name.

I could have sworn their was a substring function that could 'search' until a certain character was found.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending what's in there, you might just find it easier to put it in a stringstream and extract from that like you would with input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "Person Name";
    size_t pos = str.find(" ");
    std::cout << str.substr(0,pos);
}
```

Comment: The nice thing is that you don't have to check against `npos` in this case, as that's what `substr`'s second parameter defaults to.

Comment: @chris yeah, I made the assumption that there is indeed a space between the names at all times.

Comment: But even if there isn't, it will print the whole string :)

Comment: Cool, thanks! Now, what if I wanted to start at a specific character then go to another specific character?

Comment: @Douko Do you mean looping through a string?

Comment: I don't think so- I mean say I want to capture a substring in the string '"I love you, and me- but mostly me."' I want to be able to designate a substring from say, the comma to the dash.

Comment: @Douko there are a couple ways of doing that, but `std::string::substr` doesn't accept indexes as its second parameter -- rather the second parameter is the count so it'd be a bit trickier.